# Winform browser control "attachment" button

Tags: asp.net, ajax, winforms

We have a winform app that has a browser control on it. Previously these files (always very small 10kb etc.) were stored at a unc location. We would generate some html and load the html into the browser. If we wanted to make one of these small files available we would include in the HTML an anchor tag () WHen the html was displayed in the browser control so would be the link. The user could click on the link and the file save as dialog would appear.

We are now storing these files in the db as varbinary and thus there is no longer a physical location for the anchor tag to point to. I have several thoughts but would like the members of SO who are way smarter than me to chime in.

Option 1 in my mind would be to have an image button, anchor tag, something in the html to click on. I would handle the "onclick" either in javascript or as a postback. This seems doable for my level of knowledge EXCEPT I do not know how to get the byte[] to translate into the save as dialog for the user....do I render it to disk first?

The other idea I had was to have a button that is **NOT** in the browser control. This button would be hidden / visible if the biz rules said to show a file. Clicking on the button would then generate the byte[] which is easily turned into a file and the save as shown dialog shown in the winform app.

So any thought or all together different suggestions welcome
TIA
JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are in control of the ASP.NET web page shown in the windows forms web browser control so you can edit that page and build it the way you want.

if that is true, behavior in hosted web browser or in normal IE session is the same and I would suggest to create a bunch of hyper links or buttons in the asp.net web form page each one which a specific ID, like the ID of the file to download. then you can create an handler or a button_click event handler where you get the byte[] of the file by the clicked button/link associated file Id, or from query string if you initiated an handler call, and then you start streaming down to the browser the file content, the browser will do all what is required for you.

for example, just as a starting point, a bit of code taken from here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/d6a5087f-43b1-4782-95f1-d1376130d2c8

shows you a possible way to do this from a page load, the trick is that the call to `GetDocument` gets the proper file content for you (in this case from the query string, imagine like if we are inside an handler processing method) and returns a class `DocumentInfo` which contains the bytes. you do nor need this DocumentInfo, you can just have a method which returns `byte[]` by File Id for example...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        string queryString = this.Request.QueryString.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString)) return;

        DocumentInfo documentInfo = GetDocument(queryString);

        if (!documentInfo.HasValue) return;

        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", documentInfo.Value.Content.Length.ToString());

        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.doc");

        Response.BinaryWrite(documentInfo.Value.Content);

        Response.End();
    }
}
```